# Insert data into two table from a web form

Tags: php, mysql

table person

"person_id"
 "person_name"

---

table email

"email_id"
"email"
"person_id"

---

What is the sql comment for insert data form a web form into these tables?
In the web form I have a text box for name and dynamic text box for email

Comment: have you searched for _any_ examples how to do this?

Comment: Funny... SQL has been downgraded from *language* to *comment* :-P

Answer (score 0):

Read the form values into variables, securely insert into MySQL database: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you are using POST and you set up your connection to the db i'd do it like this (i omit validation and so on, just the sript to insert data :

```
$person_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['person_name']);
$email= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO person ('person_name') VALUES ('%s')'",$person_name);
$result = mysql_query($query);

// always set your variables to a default value
$success = false;

// did the query execute successfully?
if($result){
    $success = true;
}

if($success){
  $person_id = mysql_insert_id();

  $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO email ('email','person_id') VALUES ('%s','%s')",$email,$person_id);

  $resultSecond = mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: You're not using placeholders, very bad practice

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps involved.  You will first need to [validate the user's input](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation) - don't just put it directly into the database.  Validation should be done on the server.  You can perform client-side validation with Javascript too, but this should only be done to enhance the user experience - it must not replace server-side validation.  To start, you could look at PHP's [Filter methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php), or perhaps look for a [form validation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737385/easiest-form-validation-library-for-php).

When you come to insert it into the database, I highly recommend using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of messing around with horrible escaping.

The example given on the PHP site is quite good, and should get you started.  You could also checkout:

[PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)
[Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by only SQL queries, you need to code a procedure like

```
INSERT INTO person (person_name) VALUES ('PERSON_NAME')
INSERT INTO email (email_id,email,person_id) VAUES ('EMAIL_ID','EMAIL',(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()))
```

I assumed that you can post PERSON_NAME, EMAIL_ID, EMAIL from your web form.

I think it's easy to send both EMAIL_ID, EMAIL from your autocomplete like box.