# PHP validation class and request callback issue

Tags: php, ajax, class, validation

Currently I work with a registration form and wish to look up a php validation class implement in it for validation checking, I was found a class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737385/easiest-form-validation-library-for-php) provided by SchizoDuckie, my form will use ajax request to call a file `reg_process.php`, my problem is how can I use this class to validate required fields? and send to browser with errors message if found invalid input?

This is reg_process.php:

```
<?php
include('FormValidator.php');

$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($_POST['email'])));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));
$rpassword = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['rpassword']));
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);

$validations = array(
    'name' => 'anything',
    'email' => 'email',
    'alias' => 'anything',
    'pwd'=>'anything',
    'gsm' => 'phone',
    'birthdate' => 'date');
$required = array('name', 'email', 'alias', 'pwd');
$sanatize = array('alias');

$validator = new FormValidator($validations, $required, $sanatize);

if($validator->validate($_POST))
{
    $_POST = $validator->sanatize($_POST);
    // now do your saving, $_POST has been sanatized.
    die($validator->getScript()."<script type='text/javascript'>alert('saved changes');    </script>");
}
else
{
    die($validator->getScript());
}
?>
```

ajax call:

```
$('#btn_reg').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#reg_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'reg_process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            //how to get error if found invalid
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: your ajax url is `request_registraion.php`. can you show us that file?

Comment: request_registration.php is same with reg_process.php, just corrected.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do it would be with HTTP Response Codes.

On success on the server side, respond with a 200 HTTP Response Code.  Your jQuery ajax *success* callback will catch these responses and you can do what you wish with the data.

If validation fails, respond with a 500 error if something went wrong and catch it with the *error* callback.

Responding with the right response codes will help separate the good from the bad.

Also, it's probably not a good idea to pass back javascript directly because you'd have to `eval()` it.