# adding validation to my contact form php

Tags: php, forms, validation

I've eventually got my contact form working, my next task is to add in some server side validation to the fields. Here is my php code for the form:

```
<?php
    require_once('../_inc/config/db.php');

    $postArray = $_POST;

    foreach($postArray['name'] as $row=>$Name) {
      $name=mysql_real_escape_string($Name);
      $company=mysql_real_escape_string($postArray['company'][$row]);
      $email=mysql_real_escape_string($postArray['email'][$row]);
      $contact=mysql_real_escape_string($postArray['contact'][$row]);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO registered_blue (`name`, `company`, `email`, `contact`, `day`, `event-time`, `event`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$company."','".$email."','".$contact."', '" . $postArray['event-day'] . "', '" . $postArray['event-time'] . "', '" . $postArray['event'] . "')";

      $result = mysql_query($sql);

    }

    if ($result) {
        header('Location: /blue-event/confirmed.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as  the simplest/most effective way of implementing validation on this form?

Comment: validating post data is the simplest way or use jquery validation plugin to validate data(client side) .

Comment: Stack Overlow works best if you have a specific question. Questions like this are considered offtopic

Comment: Apologies, just after some advice, so is it good enough just to test whether or not the fields are empty or not?

Comment: That depends on your requirements

Comment: Just don't want to form submitting if any fields are blank. I guess it would be good to test that a correct email format has been entered too.

Comment: How is that related to validation (which is what OP is asking about)? @YogeshSuthar

Comment: I agree with PeeHaa, but try creating a class for validations, then you pass all the fields you have and what you want to validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well define the validation you want

values are required?
I personaly use `strlen`, others use `== ''` (use trim if wished for)

Values need to be a specific type?
You should look at `preg_match` or `ctype_*` (see [these function](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php))

Numbers need to me in a specific range, use the `< <= >= >` operators.

File validation, look at extension and then mime type (always look at the mime to be sure!)

So there are tons of ways to validate and tons of things to validate so you should be make a more specific question.

I also recommend, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737385/easiest-form-validation-library-for-php). It gives you a nice start I think