# How to implement a PHP Form processing logic that is reusable?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am new to PHP and I have a lots of forms in PHP. The forms make use of the standard HTML Input fields and need to be validated on the serverside. How can I implement this, so that I do not have to write lots of boilerplate HTML over and over again, rather only write the minimal amount of code that generate the "full forms". What is the recommended approach to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: of course, if you have an example of existing projects/framworks that do this already, than this would be great too as answer. thanks

Comment: You can use template engines, then you can pass some parameters to tell the template which fields of forms that you want in this page. I was using the template engine introduced by Yaf in the business.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737385/easiest-form-validation-library-for-php) and its answers may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer to do it all yourself, you should at least do it PHP-Classes which will save you from re-writing (if done right ;-)). Handle attributes of the fields through an assoc array, e.g. like this:

```
<?php

   $form = new Form("MyInput", array ("submit" => "myform.php") );

   $form->AddField("input_text", array ("label" => "Your name") );

?>
```

To handle validation, you could use attributes such as

```
   $form->AddField("input_text", array (
        "label" => "Your name" , 
        "validate" => "required"
   ) );
```

(*Only examples, there's a lot of code releated to this which you'd need to write once...*)

That should be useful for learning purposes...

Next, you could use JS to validate. Pls. note that JS does client-side validation only and you cannot rely on it being executed (user might have turned of JS in his browser), so you still MUST validate in PHP when receiving the data. (And you could use JS-Libraries for that - I've used [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org) and was quite happy with it...)

If you want to skip that experience, use Frameworks or Templating Engines.

Comment: Hello MBaas, this looks great! Thanks. You are writing about Frameworks and Template  Engines. Can you maybe elaborate on them too, if you know one, that does work like you described in your post, it would be kind to name them. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for parsley. This seems great. I have used jqueryvalidation.org so far. but parsley seems very promising. thanks.

Comment: Hi Tim,  the code that I've shown was inspired by something that I wrote for a client as part of a contract - I implemented such controls for all HTML-Controls, and that was quite a bit of work, but very rewarding, too, and the fact that one class was used over and over again has been most helpful. :) If you choose to work with existing products, Smarty (as mentioned by other posters) is a good choice (http://www.smarty.net/ ). And there's an endless number of frameworks, my suggestions are http://www.yiiframework.com/ , http://laravel.com/ , http://symfony.com/ and http://framework.zend.com/

Comment: And these frameworks will, in one way or another, aldo address the issue of form-validation, so what you actually choose might also depend on the app you're working on...

Comment: Hello MBaas, first of all, thanks so much for your answer! It helps me so much! Thanks! You answer is really what I am looking for: The emphasize is not on validation rather to reuse HTML Elements with the least code possible. I will look into the frameworks but as far as i can tell, they really lack of what your answer is about? They do not provide a declarative way of defining HTML elements? But I will have a look. (it seems I currently can not upvote, I have to less reputation I will doo as soon as i can). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a form template. Consider using a method (of class `View)`:

```
private static function capture($view_filename, array $view_data)
{   
    extract($view_data, EXTR_SKIP);

    ob_start();

    require $view_filename;

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And call the static function `capture` (caution: consider using of [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) to print objects) Pseudo-code:

```
echo View::capture('template', array('id' => '1', 'class' => 'userForm', 'inputs' => array(0 => array('label' => 'Name', 'type' => 'text'), 1 => array('label' => 'Password', 'type' => 'password')));
```