# PHP Form Validation framework JQuery Format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I started web developing some time ago but just now I've engaged some bigger size projects.

I started using bootstrap and JQuery along with JQuery Validation Plugin which makes it really easy to validate forms on the client side.

I was wondering if there's any library for PHP that validates user input given certain restrictions (on the same format as for the JQuery Validation plugin), so I could implement server side checks easily.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this post.  While not a specific answer to your question, it may instead give you a different way to look at you server-side checks.

[Easiest Form validation library for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737385/easiest-form-validation-library-for-php)