# php inserting data with filter and validation

Tags: php, html

I have a database and I want to make sure that fields are not empty, and if not I want to save them into database with this sanitized function. So after fields are filled and sanitized I want to save them to database.

```
<?php
// Initialize variables to null.
$nameError ="";
$emailError ="";

                    // On submitting form below function will execute.
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                            if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                                $nameError = "Name is required";
                                } else {
                                $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                                // check name only contains letters and whitespace
                                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                                $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
                            }
                            }

                    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                        $emailError = "Email is required";
                        } else {
                        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                        // check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
                        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
                        $emailError = "Invalid email format";
                    }
                    }   


}
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
//php code ends here
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation with PHP - Demo Preview</title>
<meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
<!--<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="maindiv">
<div class="form_div">
<div class="title">
<h2>Form Validation with PHP.</h2>
</div>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<h2>Form</h2>
<span class="error">* required field.</span><br/>
Name:
<input class="input" name="name" type="text" value=""><br/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span><br/>
E-mail:
<input class="input" name="email" type="text" value=""><br/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailError;?></span><br/>

<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Arulkumar, great code and great help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

**html side:**
For checking on inputs like name and email, I suggest using the html attribute `required` on your input tags. And also, you can utilize the type of input like `email`:

```
<input name="name" type="name" required>
<input name="email" type="email" required>
```

[required attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) in html checks during submission of form whether you have inputted a value. If there are no values, then a warning will prompt and tell you that it is required.

an [email type](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) in input tag validates whether the user input has proper format for the email.

**php side:**
your sanitize method and validation have no problems, but if you are looking for the best implementation regarding form validation, I suggest using a function or better, add it in a form validator class. There is a simple example here of a good validator class: [Easiest Form validation library for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737385/easiest-form-validation-library-for-php)

You can make your own class based on your preferences and of course you can experience the advantages of using [oop design](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762) in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I need it from php side, I know html require attribute but it's not safe... thank you a lot, best regards

Comment: @FAMO_php, what you said is true about the risk of using sanitation on the html side, since html scripts can be manipulated on the browser.. I'll add another suggestion regarding php sanitation later..