# Lightweight HTML/JavaScript framework for business forms

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to build multiple business forms with basic validations.

Example field types:

- required field
- date (datepicker)
- time (timepicker)
- email
- money
- integer number (+ optional min/max value)
- decimal number (specify precision)
- phone number
- social security number
- zip code
- credit card number
- masked text (+ optional regex validation)
- field with server side validation
- etc.

Is there a lightweight library or framework that provides some or most of those field types out of the box as well as the ability to create custom fields with validations?

Comment: Not a framework, but have you ever used HTML's native [pattern matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) on inputs? It has [>90% support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern) in vendors. It allows for matching a regex client-side. Of course, as with any solution, server-side is necessary as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can these. I would think that a server-side validation is good too in addition to front-end validation

1. Use HTML5 (frontend) native validation
2. https://github.com/Zhouzi/GentleForm
3. PHP some people have created their own class they shared [Easiest Form validation library for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737385/easiest-form-validation-library-for-php)
4. JQuery validation https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use [vuito](https://github.com/mathix420/vuito), since it's template-based and isomorphic you can share your validations between front and back-end super easily. The package weight less than 1.3kB.